# Cron jobs running 9hours 15min late

Tags: cron

I have a Cron Job set to run Nightly at 22:01 followed buy three others at 23:59 02:10 and 02:15

The Cron log shows that they are kicked off at the correct time..

:cron.log file snippet:

```
Apr 12 22:01:01 toaster /USR/SBIN/CRON[6374]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.daily/DS_Daily.sh)
Apr 12 23:59:01 toaster /USR/SBIN/CRON[8062]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.daily/do-WebStats.sh)
Apr 13 02:10:01 toaster /USR/SBIN/CRON[9376]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.daily/get-arin.sh)
Apr 13 02:15:01 toaster /USR/SBIN/CRON[9415]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.daily/blocker.sh)
```

So all good there. However the jobs do not actually run till 09:15 AM as per the log files of the Scripts themselves...

:Snippets from Log Files:

```
Start DS_Daily Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:15:01 MDT 2016
Start Webstats Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:16:32 MDT 2016
Start Get Arin Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:22:28 MDT 2016
Start Blocker Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:15:41 MDT 2016
```

Which, to me anyway seems to be very strange indeed...

The Crontab looks like this....

```
59 23 * * * root /etc/cron.daily/do-WebStats.sh
10 2 * * * root /etc/cron.daily/get-arin.sh
15 2 * * * root /etc/cron.daily/blocker.sh
1 22 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5 root /etc/cron.daily/DS_Daily.sh
```

And really I'm at my wit's end here....

All of the scripts start with a simple echo command to dump $date to the Log file (As seen above) so the very first thing is to write the time and date tot he Log file, Part of the DS_Daily.sh is to FTP some files to a remote Server and their datetime stamps are also 9:15am...

As an aside, Clocks have been checked...

```
[10:19 root@toaster log] > date
Wed Apr 13 10:19:30 MDT 2016
[10:19 root@toaster log] > hwclock
Wed 13 Apr 2016 10:19:34 AM MDT  -0.516705 seconds
[10:19 root@toaster log] >
```

If it helps or makes a difference....

```
openSUSE 12.2 (i586) VERSION = 12.2 CODENAME = Mantis
Kernel Information:  Linux 3.4.6-2.10-desktop i686
```

Any insight or thoughts on this would be appreciated....

Comment: your logs shows that `DS_Daily.sh` was executed `22:01:01`, your logs maybe reflect when it's done, instead of when it starts? i'd suggest to look into your app, this is not cron issue.

Comment: again, there is no issue with cron as it executes according to schedule that is set, your app/script is doing something funky, but that's not related to `crond`. schedule another job of a simple script that does nothing but output date into a file and check that file, you'll see that it'll execute and write timeout in time of script executed (without any delays).

Comment: I had thought of that, but the Script DS_Daily.sh takes all of 30 seconds to run from start to finish....

This is what the script write to the log file. It's the first lines of the script...

echo "==========================================" >> /var/log/DS_Daily.log
echo "Start DS_Daily Script" >> /var/log/DS_Daily.log
echo "Time: $(date)" >>  /var/log/DS_Daily.log
echo " "

Start DS_Daily Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:15:01 MDT 2016
Finished DS_Daily Script
Time: Wed Apr 13 09:15:41 MDT 2016

Time stamp on the LogFile itself...

-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root  2.6K Apr 13 09:15 DS_Daily.log

Comment: Sorry my formatting skills here are a bit lacking....

Comment: Been doing some more testing. And it seems no matter which script I run, they all show as having run int eh cron.log file, but just don;t run for whatever reason. I suspect in 9 hours or so I will get he E-Mails telling me they ran.

All of the scripts run manually from the command line all run in under five minutes, one in umber 30 seconds. It's only when CRON tries to run them that the delay occurs...

Comment: What surprises me most is that you have hours between the various starts of your scripts, yet they all end up logged within minutes... As if they are added to a queue and the queue only starts moving forward again at 9:15. Is there anything else running that is using the same resources? Something testing for pid files?